# What i have to do after i'm working with tf idf and chi square

Tags: text, tf-idf, chi-squared, mining

In text mining, i wanna ask what i have to do after I did a tf idf and chi square for terms.

Tf idf is like a different file with chi square. Right?

Is it right if i did a tf idf matrix times chi square weight for every terms?

Comment: Sorry for the grammar, i just fix that. Did you know the answer? Thanks if you want to sharing because i desperate for looking a paper just to answer my question, by the way this is for my paper to finish my undergraduate degree. Thanks

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/ might be a better forum for this question.  Cross Validated is for statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, and data visualization questions while StackOverflow is for programming questions.